# Zip operations in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a zipped object in python containing these values:

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0]
 [1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1]
 [0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]]   [(0.4472135954999579, 0), (0.5, 0), (0.3779644730092272, 0), (0.5773502691896258, 1), (0.4472135954999579, 1), (0.7071067811865475, 1)]
```

I want to transform them into:

```
[0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]   (0.4472135954999579, 0)
[0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0]   (0.5, 0)
[1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]   (0.3779644730092272, 0)
[0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1]   (0.5773502691896258, 1)
[0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1]   (0.4472135954999579, 1)
[0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]   (0.7071067811865475, 1)
```

is there a neat way in doing this in python without looping too much.. and as much as possible already sorted using the second column.

results:

```
[(array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int64), (0.4472135954999579, 0)), (array([0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], dtype=int64), (0.5, 0)), (array([1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int64), (0.3779644730092272, 0)), (array([0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], dtype=int64), (0.5773502691896258, 1)), (array([0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1], dtype=int64), (0.4472135954999579, 1)), (array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], dtype=int64), (0.7071067811865475, 1))]
```

Comment: It looks like your "zipped object" is an iterable of two elements, a 2D numpy X*Y array and a length-Y list of 2-tuples, and you desired output is an iterable of Y iterables, each of a 1D numpy X array and a 2-tuple. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, and as much as possible i want to sort it using the second column.

Comment: I don't understand what's the transformation here.

Comment: Your tags are all over the place. Arraylist is from Java and Python 2 and 3 zips do different things. Please fix.

Comment: Instead of just confirming that my guess was right in a comment, please edit the question so it stands on its own, clear to anyone who reads it. You may want to read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and other relevant help articles.

Comment: OK, now that you've posted your actual input—you don't have the format you say you have, you already have exactly the format you say you want. So you don't need any transformation at all. The only thing left to do is sort it. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the input you described—a "zipped object" that has two elements, an XxY numpy matrix and a Y-length list of pairs:

First, let's unpack your "zipped object" into its two elements:

```
matrix, pairs = zipped
```

Now we want an iterable that gives us one row of the matrix, and the corresponding pair from the list, without changing the order of either.. But that's just `zip`!

```
zip(matrix, pairs)
```

Or, if you want it to be a one-liner:

```
zip(*zipped)
```

As you can see:

```
>>> for row, pair in zip(*zipped):
...     print(row, pair)
[0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0] (0.4472135954999579, 0)
[0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0] (0.5, 0)
[1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] (0.3779644730092272, 0)
[0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1] (0.5773502691896258, 1)
[0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1] (0.4472135954999579, 1)
[0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0] (0.7071067811865475, 1)
```

If you want to sort it by the second column, that's easy. You have an iterable; you want to sort it by its second element; just use an `itemgetter` as the sorting `key`:

```
>>> for row, pair in sorted(zip(*zipped), key=operator.itemgetter(1)):
...     print(row, pair)
[1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] (0.3779644730092272, 0)
[0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0] (0.4472135954999579, 0)
[0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1] (0.4472135954999579, 1)
[0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0] (0.5, 0)
[0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1] (0.5773502691896258, 1)
[0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0] (0.7071067811865475, 1)
```

---

But the input you pasted is completely different. In fact, it's already in exactly the form you're looking for, so  you don't have to do anything at all, except the sorting at the end:

```
>>> zipped = [(array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int64), (0.4472135954999579, 0)), (array([0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], dtype=int64), (0.5, 0)), (array([1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int64), (0.3779644730092272, 0)), (array([0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], dtype=int64), (0.5773502691896258, 1)), (array([0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1], dtype=int64), (0.4472135954999579, 1)), (array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], dtype=int64), (0.7071067811865475, 1))]
>>> for row, pair in sorted(zipped, key=operator.itemgetter(1)):
...     print(row, pair)
```

Comment: when i tried this "matrix, pairs = zipped"  it gave me a "ValueError: too many values to unpack"

but when i try to:
    for x,y in zipped:
       print(x," ",y)

its output is correct

Comment: @xx4xx4 Then whatever `zipped` is, it isn't in the format you described. Try this: `print(list(zipped))`, then paste the result into your question.

Comment: @xx4xx4 As a side note, you really don't need `print(x, " ", y)` unless you need two spaces between the pairs instead of one for some reason; `print(x, y)` is usually perfectly readable.

Comment: oh its just an old habit from other programming language.. btw already pasted the result